# Partitioning $\{0,1\}^n$ into $n$ sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattices, coding-theory

I am working on an answer to the question

[Magic trick based on deep mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9754/magic-trick-based-on-deep-mathematics)

and came across the following problem: I am trying to partition the cube $\{0,1\}^n$ into $n$ sets $P_1,\dots,P_n$ such that, for any point $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ and any $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, there exists a point $y\in P_i$ such that $x$ and $y$ differ in at most one term.  Using my computer I know that this is possible for $n\leq 4$, impossible for $n=5$ and $6$, and possible for $n=7$ and $8$ (by brute force integer programming).  For example, one solution for $n=4$ is \begin{align*}
P_{1} & =xyyy\text{ or }xxxx\\
P_{2} & =xyxx\text{ or }xyyx\\
P_{3} & =xxyx\text{ or }xyxy\\
P_{4} & =xxxy\text{ or }xxyy
\end{align*}
where $x$ and $y$ are separate values in $\{0,1\}$.  My question is:  can this partition (or something like it) extend to $n=8$ in a simple way?  Alternatively, are there *any* values of $n$ for which there is a simple and natural partition?

To clarify my notation here is an explicit list of the $P_i$'s for $n=4$:

\begin{align*}
P_{1} & =0111\text{ or }1000\text{ or }0000\text{ or }1111\\
P_{2} & =0100\text{ or }1011\text{ or }0110\text{ or }1001\\
P_{3} & =0010\text{ or }1101\text{ or }0101\text{ or }1010\\
P_{4} & =0001\text{ or }1110\text{ or }0011\text{ or }1100
\end{align*}

Comment: $n=4$, your example, $i=1$, how does $yxyx$ differ in at most one term from a point in $P_1=\{\,xyyy,xxxx\,\}$? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, and you mean $P_1=\{\,0111,1000,0000,1111\,\}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, that is exactly what I mean by $P_1$.  Both $0111$ and $1000$ are of the form $xyyy$.

Comment: How does $0101$ get into $xyyy,xxxx$?

Comment: Ack!  Sorry!  Edited my comment.  It goes $0101 \mapsto 0111$.  Revising the question...

Comment: My question https://mathoverflow.net/q/243459/7709, also motivated by a magic trick, asks for such a partition with the stronger property that, given any $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ and any $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, there exists $y \in P_i$ such that $x_i = y_i$ and $x$ and $y$ differ in at most one term. In this case a covering code argument shows that $n$ has to be a power of two.

Comment: @JoshC: did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code ? Your specific question might need more, but this should help for a start.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a binary code with *covering radius* 1, which is in general a well studied and difficult problem.

Basically you need a collection of codewords such that the union of the spheres with radius 1 around them cover the whole space.

If you took any of your collections, say $P_1$ for length 4, you could obtain what you need for length $n=8,$ by the following construction.

Take $P_i,P_j$, create the sets $U\otimes P_i$ and $P_j \otimes U$ where $U$ (the universe) is the set of all $4-$tuples. The union of these two sets will give you a covering code with radius 1. So picking $i=j=1,$ gives
\begin{align*}
P_{1} \otimes U & =0111xxxx\text{ or }1000xxxx\text{ or }0000xxxx\text{ or }1111xxxx\\
U\otimes P_{1} & =xxxx0111\text{ or }xxxx1000\text{ or }xxxx0000\text{ or }xxxx1111
\end{align*}
where $xxxx$ means we take all possible bit patterns of length $4.$

**Edit:** A simpler and optimal construction is to take the codewords of the perfect Hamming code with length 7 bits and minimum distance 3. This code has 16 codewords, and covering radius 1. Add a zero bit and a 1 bit at the end of each codeword to obtain an optimal set of only 32 codewords covering $\{0,1\}^8$ with covering radius 1.

Since all binary Hamming codes with lengths $2^m-1$ are perfect, and have $2^{2^m-m-1}$ codewords, the above construction yields optimal covering codes with covering radius 1 and $2^{2^m-m}$ codewords when $n=2^m.$

It is known in general that for any length $n$ the quantity $2^n/(n+1)$ is a lower bound to the cardinality of any binary code with covering radius 1.

Comment: OP asks for more: a partition into $n$ covering codes of radius 1.  Furthermore, an optimal code has size $2^n/(n+1)$ (not $2^n/n$).  Hamming cosets do indeed partition the space, giving $n+1$ of them, not $n$.  One could take the $(n+1)$-st coset and divvy it up among other cosets to get exactly $n$. Hamming codes exist for $n$ one less than a power of $2$, and perhaps the difference between $n$ and $n+1$ provides enough wiggle room for other values.  You might look in Cohen-Honkala-Litsuyn-Lobstein to see what error term is in the asymptotic size of the smallest known $R=1$ covering code.